# Memory exception on large data asignment in python

Tags: python

I am trying to load a large file, read it line by line, and create a tuple.
Here is my code:

```
for line in fileinput.input([filename],openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("utf-8")):
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) < 3:
            continue
        user,pwd = ParseLine(line)
        luser = user.lower()
        # newData = luser + ':' + pwd
        if (luser + ':' + pwd) in dinctdatas:
            continue
        dinctdatas[luser + ':' + pwd] = 1
        result.append((user,pwd))

return result
```

My code works fine with smaller files but throws **memory exception** when I try using files of 700MB for example. Although I have 16 GB of memory in my server, I still get this exception. I am using python 3.

Comment: You're running out of virtual memory, not physical memory.

Comment: Python has a limit of the process size.

Comment: Is this executed by a 32bit Python version? If so, use 64bit version instead.

Comment: @MichaelButscher 64it

Comment: @Barmar so how to reach larger proccess size?